# Dict comprehension with lambda function and scalar

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, dictionary-comprehension

I have dict comprehension with lambda function and scalar:

```
d = {k: lambda x : x.sum() if 'a' in k else 'yes' for k in ['bac','sss','asa']}
print (d)
{'bac': <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000000031891E0>, 
 'sss': <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000000000D887EA0>, 
 'asa': <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000000000D887B70>}
```

If want both scalars it working nice:

```
d = {k: 'no' if 'a' in k else 'yes' for k in ['bac','sss','asa']}
print (d)
{'bac': 'no', 'sss': 'yes', 'asa': 'no'}
```

Expected output - combination of scalars and lambda function:

```
print (d)
{'bac': <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000000031891E0>, 
 'sss': 'yes', 
 'asa': <function <dictcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000000000D887B70>}
```

What is happening? Why it is not working? What is the correct approach?

Comment: `d = {k: (lambda x : x.sum()) if 'a' in k else 'yes' for k in ['bac','sss','asa']}` works (wrapping lambda in parentheses) but I don't know why. Presumably some of the rest of the expression gets wrapped up in lambda in your current approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is parsed as follows (note the location of the parentheses):

```
{k: lambda x : (x.sum() if 'a' in k else 'yes') for k in ['bac','sss','asa']}
#              ^                              ^
```

You want:

```
{k: (lambda x : x.sum()) if 'a' in k else 'yes' for k in ['bac','sss','asa']}
#   ^                  ^
```

This is because `lambda` has [lower precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `if`-`else`.

A simpler example also illustrates this:

```
>>> lambda x: 0 if False else True
<function <lambda> at 0x7efdbe55abf8>
>>> lambda x: (0 if False else True)
<function <lambda> at 0x7efdbe55ac80>
>>> (lambda x: 0) if False else True
True
```

Answer (score 4):

```
d = {k: (lambda x : x.sum()) if 'a' in k else 'yes' for k in ['bac','sss','asa']}
```

should work. The reason (as far as I understand) is that boundaries for parsing lambda is overlapping with your comprehension — basically, python parsing your lambda as `x.sum() if 'a' in k else 'yes'` — with reference to locals